# Bets way to find records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How to list all users that dont have achievement.title="year"? 
This is what i have so far:

> User.all.includes(:achievements).where.not("achievements.title = ?",
>   "year").references(:achievements)

but it doesn't give me users who have no achievements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if your db is PostgreSQL:

```
User.includes(:achievements)
    .where("achievements.title != ? or achievements.id is null", "year")
    .references(:achievements)
```